# Spark Repartition. What would be a good number for a 10 Gb File

Tags: java, apache-spark, partition

I'm trying to work with a 10 Gb CSV File. I'm not sure of where the probleme could come from  but  my worker often stop before the end.

I guess it could come from bad repartitionning. That's why I wonder what would be an average number of repartition for a 10 Gb file of 10 Cols

So far, I've tried 1 and 50 , but it failed. I wonder if I should try something like 300 or if a normal repartioning would rather be between 1 and 10

Sorry for asking this, but every test last more than 2 ou 3 hours...

Thansk for your help

Comment: Do you mean GB when you write Go?

Comment: Yes, sorry I though Go was international, but obviously, it's not

Comment: The number of partitions is not solely linked to the size of the dataset. The only rule of thumb is "the size of one partition should be small enough to fit an executor, the size of all active partitions combined should be small enough to fit the cluster". If you have 2GB per executor, your partition size should never reach 2GB. If you have 16GB in your cluster, the size of all partitions being processed at a given point in time should not have a sum approaching 16GB. So the real question is : how much memory does each partition need to do your job, e.g : what do you do with the CSV ?